# What are mysql.session@localhost and mysql.sys@localhost user accounts good for?

Tags: mysql

I freshly installed a MySQL instance and found it has two user accounts: mysql.session@localhost and mysql.sys@localhost in the result of `SELECT User, Host From mysql.user` - I didn't create those. Can I safely delete them? Or are they necessary to the MySQL database installation?

Answer (score 4):

Don't delete them as these users are used by MySql internally. You can read more about it at MySql reference manual : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reserved-users.html

Comment: Updated link to documentation (previous 404s)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/reserved-accounts.html